# Stuck Screen Using NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970M on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, screen

I'm facing a problem with **NVIDIA** driver on **Ubuntu 16.04**. I've been reading overwhelmingly of forums and blogs, although, nothing helped me at the moment.

I'm using a Clevo **P650RE** laptop, which there is the bellow configuration:

```
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970M 3GB 
Core i7-6700HQ Processor (6M Cache up to 3.50 GHz)
32GB DDR4 2400MHZ
```

After installation of Ubuntu 16.04, a popup is showed with the follow message: "Installation is complete, You need to restart the computer in order to use the new installation"

Thus, I click on the button "Restart Now", then the laptop get stuck and I'm obligated to hold the button power and force the restart.

When I get the Login Screen and type my password then the Ubuntu gets stuck,then once again I have to hold the power button.

I saw the bellow procedure:

To start Ubuntu into safe mode (Recovery Mode) and remove the NVIDIA driver type at terminal:

```
$ apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
```

After it, I could go through the login screen and I got able to use some applications such as Firefox and Terminal, however, when I click on System Settings, then the Ubuntu stuck again and the only way I have is holding the power bottom.

I tried to install the NVIDIA driver (**NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.35.run**):

```
LINUX X64 (AMD64/EM64T) DISPLAY DRIVER
Version:    367.35
Release Date:    2016.7.15
Operating System:    Linux 64-bit
Language:    English (US)
File Size:    72.1 MB
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work as well.
Does someone has an idea for this issue?
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Have you tried solution from http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics with switching to tty and installation of drivers from ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa repository ? Use `sudo apt-get install nvidia-367` instead of `sudo apt-get install nvidia-364`.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is fixed, the solution is on the below link:

http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/clevo-p650re-running-ubuntu-16-06-stuck-nvidia-geforce-gtx-970m.794709